# How to set DataGridViewButtonCell Text In A Column with Multiple Controls

Tags: vb.net, text, datagridview, cell

I have a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn that holds different types of DataGridViewCells (Combobox, Text & Button).

[image: Different DataGridView Cells]

Here is how I build the datagridview rows:

```
Public Shared Function BuildDgvRow(ByVal tq As clsTabsQuestion) As DataGridViewRow
    Dim Row As New DataGridViewRow
    Dim ComboBoxCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    Dim CellBtn As New DataGridViewButtonCell //File Upload
    Dim CellTxtQ As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell //Cell question
    Dim CellTxt As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell //Cell txt

    CellTxtQ = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell

    //Build row
    With Row
        //Add cell that will contain question
        .Cells.Add(CellTxtQ)

        //Add CheckBox / Button / Text to the other cell that will contain the answer
        Select Case tq.sType
            Case "YesNo"
                ComboBoxCell = New DataGridViewComboBoxCell()
                ComboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(New String() {"Yes", "No", "N/A"})
                .Cells.Add(ComboBoxCell)
            Case "FileUpload"
                CellBtn = New DataGridViewButtonCell
                .Cells.Add(CellBtn)
            Case "Text"
                CellTxt = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
                .Cells.Add(CellTxt)
        End Select

        //Set row values
        .SetValues({tq.Title, ""})
        .Tag = tq
    End With

    Return Row
End Function
```

I cannot seem to get any "Text" property from the DataGridViewButtonCell class. Is there a way to set text on a DataGridViewButtonCell? This is a questionnaire and users are able to create their own. Therefore they have a choice to choose a combobox, text or button as an answer to their question.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation I figured out my problem ... When I tried using the `CellBtn.Value` I forgot that I was resetting the row value to an empty string. Silly me.

Here's how I solved it (two ways)

### Setting Text using DataGridViewButtonCell.Value

```
Public Shared Function BuildDgvRow(ByVal tq As clsTabsQuestion) As DataGridViewRow
    Dim Row As New DataGridViewRow
    Dim ComboBoxCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    Dim CellBtn As New DataGridViewButtonCell //File Upload
    Dim CellTxtQ As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell //Cell question
    Dim CellTxt As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell //Cell txt

    CellTxtQ = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell

    //Build row
    With Row
        //Add cell that will contain question
        .Cells.Add(CellTxtQ)

        //Add CheckBox / Button / Text to the other cell that will contain the answer
        Select Case tq.sType
            Case "YesNo"
                ComboBoxCell = New DataGridViewComboBoxCell()
                ComboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(New String() {"Yes", "No", "N/A"})
                .Cells.Add(ComboBoxCell)
            Case "FileUpload"
                CellBtn = New DataGridViewButtonCell
                CellBtn.Value = "ASdasdwd"
                .SetValues({tq.Title, CellBtn.Value})
                .Cells.Add(CellBtn)
            Case "Text"
                CellTxt = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
                .Cells.Add(CellTxt)
        End Select

        //Set values
        If tq.sType <> "FileUpload" Then .SetValues({tq.Title, ""})
        .Tag = tq
    End With

    Return Row
End Function
```

### Setting Text using DataGridViewRow.SetValue

```
Public Shared Function BuildDgvRow(ByVal tq As clsTabsQuestion) As DataGridViewRow
    Dim Row As New DataGridViewRow
    Dim ComboBoxCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    Dim CellBtn As New DataGridViewButtonCell //File Upload
    Dim CellTxtQ As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell //Cell question
    Dim CellTxt As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell //Cell txt

    CellTxtQ = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell

    //Build row
    With Row
        //Add cell that will contain question
        .Cells.Add(CellTxtQ)

        //Add CheckBox / Button / Text to the other cell that will contain the answer
        Select Case tq.sType
            Case "YesNo"
                ComboBoxCell = New DataGridViewComboBoxCell()
                ComboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(New String() {"Yes", "No", "N/A"})
                .Cells.Add(ComboBoxCell)
            Case "FileUpload"
                CellBtn = New DataGridViewButtonCell
                .Cells.Add(CellBtn)
            Case "Text"
                CellTxt = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
                .Cells.Add(CellTxt)
        End Select

        //Set values
        If tq.sType = "FileUpload" Then .SetValues({tq.Title, "Upload"}) Else .SetValues({tq.Title, ""})
        .Tag = tq
    End With

    Return Row
End Function
```